# What kind of four wire connector is this?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Would someone be able to identify this four wire connector (red/black/green/white)? It's behind a blank panel on a wall adjacent to a light switch. I believe there's a second one in the wall cavity.

My guess would be that it's some proprietary connector for a 3-way switch where you attach all the wires to the connect then just plug it into the switch.

They could also be audio related - there are two speakers in the ceiling and when I bought the house the former owner said this is where the speaker wires were. There are also two wires on the outdoor wall between screws (that may have been for outdoor speaker mounts.)

In the wall cavity there are some Ethernet cables and other unidentified wires. If they're electrical wires I assume it's not to code given that there's no box containing everything.

[image: Photo of open wall cavity and assorted unidentifiable wires]

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I've been hesitant to touch the wires (with a multimeter for example) because I haven't been able to identify the breaker for this room - that's work in progress and the subject of another question.

Comment: Converted comments into an answer... as it should be.

Comment: Code specifies that media and low voltage cables can't be in the same box as regular 120v wiring.  When you come across other wires that are not in a box, it's pretty safe that it is low voltage.  Also, 14 gauge wire is the minimum you will find in home electrical, so thinner than that is low voltage (again, assuming a mad man didn't wire the house).

Comment: Well, you should see my breaker panel..

Comment: Ha, sounds like you'll be back.  Keep posting good questions and good pictures and you'll get answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disconnected a couple of these wiring blocks to find "RIACON" written on the side. A few google searches later and I've determined this is a "spring clamp terminal block" from [Metz Connect](https://www.metz-connect.com) (I think.)

All that wiring has turned out to be audio for, among other things, the speakers in the ceiling.

[image]

Comment: Glad you were able to figure this out!

Answer (score 4):

Audio would make sense since the wires are white-black-white-black. That would match up to the two speakers you talked about.

Any line-voltage wires for switches or dimmers would have to be in an electrical box, so that leaves us with low-voltage and media cables as options (or a very bad electrician!).

I was looking around at home audio equipment and I noticed that [4-conductor in-wall speaker wire](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003L1AD48) follows the same color pattern of Red-black-green-white that your connector has.

Although I don't know exactly what this connector is for, home audio seems very, very likely.

Comment: Mystified why the owner didn't leave the wall plate behind with all the connectors.

Comment: Maybe it was wired for a certain home audio system/control panel, and they decided never to install it?  It is odd because that connector seems like it would have come with the panel and not individually.  Any idea where that network cable goes?  Do you have a "Media panel" in the house that might have brand names on it?

Comment: Yeah I traced the network cable. The former owner wired eth, coax, phone, and media up the wazoo. No media panel. Just about everything is from Monoprice. Near the breaker panel I counted 11 eth cables and nearly as many cut phone wires and coax. Not sure where everything terminates. I've pulled cut cables out of floors and walls around the house, it's almost comical. Each new owner comes in, re-wires, existing stuff gets left behind. It's an old house with history I guess!

Comment: Though this audio system could be from the second owner previous. The speaker grilles are coated with a thick layer of paint. No idea why anyone would do that even if they're not using it.

Comment: People can be amazingly lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Splice blocks don't *require* color codes.  It appears this manufacturer has provided them for convenience, guessing it'll be used for North American mains power (black & white for hot & neutral, red for switched or "alt" hot, green for safety ground).

However it appears they are disregarding those color codes and using it for speakers.  That's fine.

If you pretend white is yellow, it also matches up to telephone color codes.

Comment: I turned one around and on the backside where the wires are locked down is L+, L-, inR-, R+. Curious now about what the plug into!

Comment: @Matt sounds like the builder was covering all bases!!